# tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention's argument key_dim sometimes not matches to paper's example

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, transformer-model, attention-model

For example, I have input with shape (1, 1000, 10) (so, `src.shape` wil be `(1, 1000, 10)`, which means the sequence length is 1000, and the dimension is 10. Then:

- This works (random `num_head` and `key_dim`):

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Model, self).__init__()
            self.attention1 = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=20, key_dim=9)
            self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")

        def call(self, src) :
            output = self.attention1(src, src)
            output = tf.reshape(output, [1, 10000])
            output = self.dense(output)
            return output
```

- And this works too (random `num_head` and `key_dim`) :

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Model, self).__init__()
            self.attention1 = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=123, key_dim=17)
            self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")

        def call(self, src):
            output = self.attention1(src, src)
            output = tf.reshape(output, [1, 10000])
            output = self.dense(output)
            return output
```

So, this layer works with whatever `num_heads` and `key_dim`, which does not match the paper idea. (It works because no error report, and it able to train)

In the paper, 'attention is all you need', it says `key_dim` is the dimension of key for each head, not the original head dimension, and thus `key_dim` should equal to `embed_dim`/`head_num`. So, if we want to have a `head_num` of 5, the `key_dim` has to be 2, if `embedding_dim` is 10.

[the screen shot from the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MUe3.png)

Also, from the keras attention class discription, the `key_dim` is Size of each attention head for query and key, which matches to the paper idea.

[the screen shot from the class discription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRRGN.png)

Therefore, why `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` able to take unmatched dimension. When it takes the unmatching dimension, how does it work internally with these extra weight parameters?

- Some of the question descriptions are cite from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034327/understanding-key-dim-and-num-heads-in-tf-keras-layers-multiheadattention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two dimensions d_k and d_v.

- key_dim corresponds to d_k, which can be more or less than d_v. d_k is the size of the key and query dimensions for each head.
- d_v = embed_dim/num_head. d_v is the size of the value for each head.

In their paper, Vaswani et al. set d_k = d_v. This, however, is not required.